# How can I How can I redirect users to different pages based on session data in PHP?redirect users to different pages based on session data in PHP?

Tags: php, session, session-state

I have a PHP/MySQL based website with folders for member pages and folders for admin pages. I want to direct the users to the different pages according to how they login - as a member or as a admin (from the main user pages) - this is the function I've tried and it doesn't work.

```html
function connectadmin($level) {
    if ($level === "Administrator"){
        include('admin/home.php');
    }elseif ($level === "Member"){
        include('member/home.php');
    }
}

connectadmin($level);
```

Comment: To redirect in PHP, use `header('Location: route/to/script.php');`. `include` is used to copy the content of other script to the current one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use header() function:

```
header('Location: admin/home.php');
```

instead of:

```
include('admin/home.php');
```

And the same about another link.